# why my method does not invoke in angular?

Tags: angular

When I clicked the icon in the web page, I cannot see the console log that I coded in my project.

Below is my simple code.

`favorite.component.html`

```
<span class="fa-star"
    [class.far]="!isFavorite"
    [class.fas]="isFavorite"
    (click)="onClick()"
></span>
```

`favorite.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css'],
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {
  isFavorite: boolean;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick(){
    console.log("clicked");
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the `onClick()` method, there is log statement, but I cannot find its message on the web page when I clicked the icon.

Comment: I can't see any mistake. Can you add a `console.log` in the `ngOnInit` and/or in the constructor ? Any error in the console instead ?

Comment: It is working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rh39aq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah. the code looks fine. I think maybe share the full html.

Comment: I think the issue is because of the `Styles` that you are using. Please do check your styles and conditions used. Try removing all styles and recheck

Answer (score 1):

It is related about the content of the `index.html`. When I replaced the code in the html with the one that `pc_coder` indicated. Then it works like a charm.